# How to rename Instance name and database name in powershell

Tags: powershell

I am very new in Power Shell.

I want to Change Database name from XYZ to XYZ_Test and Change the Instance name from ./SQLSERVER2014 to (Local)

I have done the following code but don't have idea where I am wrong.

```
# update settings in Podium.config

$configFile = $args[0]

$doc = new-object System.Xml.XmlDocument

$doc.Load($configFile)

$doc.SelectSingleNode('//connectionStrings/add[@name="XYZ"]/@connectionString').'#text' = 'Server=SQLSERVER2014;Initial Catalog=XYZ_Test;Integrated Security=SSPI'
$doc.Save($configFile)
```

Comment: What is the outcome?

Comment: @ Mathias R. Jessen- I am using this PS file for changing name of the database and Instance  on Teamcity  but it is not working. Is the code correct?

Answer (score 0):

```
$configFile = $args[0]
[xml]$doc = Get-Content $configFile

($doc.connectionStrings.add | ?{$_.name -eq 'XYZ'}).connectionString = 'Server=SQLSERVER2014;Initial Catalog=XYZ_Test;Integrated Security=SSPI' 
($doc.connectionStrings.add | ?{$_.name -eq 'XYZ'}).name = 'local'

$doc.Save($configFile)
```

This code works for me (PS v5). **UPD.** Checked on PSv2 machine - works as well.

Comment: Will it rename the instance name from ".\SQLSERVER2014" to "local"?

Comment: No. It will only replace whatever was inside `connectionString`. I tested like this: `<add name="XYZ" connectionString="SomeTextThere">` and "SomeTextThere" was replaced by the string I provided "Server=SQLSERVER2014;Initial Catalog=XYZ_Test;Integrated Security=SSPI".

Comment: @n01d- I want it to replace Instance name as well from ./SQLServer2014 to (local).

Comment: `($doc.connectionStrings.add | ?{$_.name -eq 'XYZ'}).name = 'local'` - like this?

Comment: Please see the edited answer. Just replace XYZ with your connection name.